# Open ArcGIS map on Android device

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping

I found map on ArcGIS Server I would like to use on my Android device:

https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/67697fc9eed74133aecb4b72dd348d12

What application I should use in order to use this map for navigation? Usually I'm using Locus Map software, but I can't find how to add such map.

Comment: This works in Google Chrome on a Pixel4a.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ArcGIS Explorer](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-explorer/overview).

> Part of the Esri Geospatial Cloud, the ArcGIS Explorer is a mobile app
> for Android, iOS, and Windows that delivers 24/7 access to your
> organization's digital maps. It works everywhere you go, even in
> environments without internet access. Search the map to find your
> organization's assets or make discoveries in the field. ArcGIS
> Explorer is the premier on-the-go option for taking maps to the field.

Go to "Search for maps" and search for **Vandringstigar**

Comment: ArcGIS Explorer is nice, but I can't find map I provided in link. "Vandringstigar" in map search gives nothing

Comment: I find it when I search